# Regex word filtering

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm having some difficulties in implementing a word filter. For example if the input consists of the following:

```
bad words
```

and my filter contains the words:

```
bad word words rude
```

how may I choose a regular expression that filters inputs such as these:

```
b<any characters>a<any characters>d 
b||a':;d 
b4d W0rd5
b@d word5
```

Comment: You can't. And you shouldn't. Any profanity filter will only make users more creative in devising ways to circumvent the filter (in the best case). In the worst case, you'll make a clbuttic fool out of yourself. Do you really want to stop users from writing the word `bread`, for example? Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem

Comment: The end users are not directly affected by the filter. It serves only as a moderation tool; it picks up potentially damaging content and saves the link for later evaluation.

Comment: I'd say this is a tough problem. `$hits stink` is a good example and says it all.